# What algorithm does ffmpeg use to select keyframes?

Tags: ffmpeg

Keyframes are mentioned all over the FFMPEG documentation, but I cannot find out how they are selected. My impression is that selecting keyframes might be part of the encoding, and so might differ if I use a different encoder. In that case, my question is with respect to the default encoder.

For example, if I run

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -skip_frame nokey -i my_video.mp4 -vsync vfr -frame_pts true kf-%02d.jpeg
```

I end up with some number of keyframes extracted from `my_video.mp4` with filenames like `kf-26.jpeg`, if it was the 26th frame in the video, as indicated by my last argument. What is the algorithm that selects these frames?

Comment: I frames comes from mpeg-x codecs like h264 or h265 and these frames are marked by the encoder. I-frame is a full frame and after parsing the nal units of an h264 packet the Decoder knows if its an I,P or B frame. So there is now algorithm how this selected. On encoder side U can set things like GOP size or I-Frame Interval that control how often These are sent

Comment: Thanks. You're using some terms I'm not familiar with. What are I,P and B frames? Which of these end up as keyframes?

Comment: I-Frame is the Key frame

Comment: Just Google h26 I,B,P frames to learn more

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the ffmpeg tag states: **Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/**. Please delete this.

Comment: @Christoph, thanks, I see now that I,P and B frames are features of how the video is compressed, so I guess it's the encoder that determines which are the I-frames. The question then is how does the encoder decide which frames should be encoded as I-frames?

Comment: @Rob my understanding is that superuser is for applied questions--'how can I get my computer to do X?' My question here is about what happens behind the scenes for a common command that I already know how to use, so doesn't seem suitable for superuser. It may be transpiring that the answer is not found in ffmpeg itself, in which case I can edit the question and remove the tag.

Comment: Then ask on the video stack exchange I linked to but you aren't asking a programming question.

Comment: Video stack exchange looks equally applied. Every recent question I see is about solving some practical problem re uploading or storing or recording. The tag description says it's for "engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts". Do you mean the SO ffmpeg tag only allows questions about how to use ffmpeg and not about understanding where its output came from? If so, that seems overly restrictive. But in any case, as I say, I can remove the tag, especially if the answer turns out to be about h264 or sth.

Comment: @ludog based on encoder settings, gop size/I-Frame interval could set or a default value is used. So its a fixed value based on encoder configuration, also some fancy stuff exist like on Axis IP-cameras where dynamic gop size exist to reduce bandwith. Where camera determine with an Algorithm whats a good gop size/I-Frame Interval is based on camera Scene.

Comment: Doesn't it also depend on how much one frame differs from the previous ones? i.e. if the video doesn't change much, you don't need many I-frames? For my mp4 files, anyway, which I see are encoded with h264, the distance between different I-frames varies a lot.